# Net MAUI (Blazor) Inject IJSRuntime into C# Class

Tags: javascript, blazor, interop, .net-maui

I am trying to use javascript outside the razor page. I am trying to inject IJSRuntime in another class that would handle all the javascript:

```
public class InvokeJavaScriptService 
    {
        private IJSRuntime js;
        public InvokeJavaScriptService(IJSRuntime js)
        {
            this.js = js; 
        }

        public async Task CallJsFromCSharp()
        {
            try
            {
                await js.InvokeAsync<object>("invokeJSfromCS");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
           
        }
    }
```

I register this service like this:

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<InvokeJavaScriptService>();
```

but when calling CallJsFromCSharp() I get this error:

[image]

INSTEAD of the desired outcome of triggering this function **invokeJSFromCS** in index.html:

```
<script>
        async function invokeJSfromCS() {
            var value = "C# Method called from JavaScript with parameter";
            // Invoke to call C# function from JavaScript with parameter.
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync ('MauiBlazorTestApp', 'JStoCSCall', value);
        }
    </script>
```

and then getting a callback in index.razor:

```
<!-- language: html -->
@page "/"
<div>
</div>

@code{
    <!-- language: c# -->
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
    }

    private static string content { get; set; }

    [JSInvokable] // Return call back from JavaScript with parameter to C#.
    public static void JStoCSCall(string value)
    {
        content = value;
    }

}
```

It is possible to inject IJSRuntime into a razor page like this:
@inject IJSRuntime, shouldn't it be possible to inject into a c# class well, how do I make this work please?

Comment: did you try this on your class? [Inject]
        public IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; protected set; }

Comment: Injecting IJSRuntime into a class the way you did is perfectly fine, I think your problem is somewhere else. At which point did you call `CallJSFromCSharp` in your component? In Blazor Server at least (stands to reason this applies to MAUI as well) it is not possible to call JS functions before the component was rendered. So you should either call your JS function in `OnAfterRender` or some UI trigger like a button

Comment: Also I think you probably have to provide the component name in `DotNet.invokeMethodAsync ('MauiBlazorTestApp', 'JStoCSCall', value);` otherwise I´m pretty sure it´s not going to find your callback. But I´d make sure the call to JS works first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a sample to test inject IJSRuntime into C# class, and it worked well.

MyService.cs:

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
namespace MauiAppTest.Data
{
public class MyService
{
    private IJSRuntime jSRuntime;
    public MyService(IJSRuntime jSRuntime)
    {
        this.jSRuntime = jSRuntime;
    }
    public void test()
    {
        jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Alert");
    }
}
}
```

And the .razor:

```
@using MauiAppTest.Data
@inject MyService myService
@code {
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    myService.test();
}
}
```

**And then I try to pass the value from JS to the razor page:**

```
@inject IJSRuntime js
private string message{ get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("Myjs", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
}
[JSInvokable]
public void Setvalue(string value) => message = value;
```

And the Js Function:

```
<script>
    function Myjs(instance) {
         var value = "hello";
         instance.invokeMethodAsync('Setvalue', value);
    }
</script>
```

The value can be passed to the razor page.

Comment: The injection of IJSRuntime jSRuntime still gives a null. Is there something else needs to be done here.

Comment: Did you try my code? It should work. @PeterMarshall